# Php: Data variable is not scoped to child template file

Tags: php

I'm trying to render a table if it has matching record data:

```
// high level template file

<?php
$dummyRequestData = [
  'data' => [
    // 2d array contents removed
];

$tradeInRequestData = $dummyRequestData;


function renderRequestDataTable(string $requestStatus) {
  global $tradeInRequestData;
  // conditional checks removed for bug isolation

  require_once(__DIR__ . "/../components/requestDataTable.php");

?>

// a lot of HTML removed

<div id="openRequestBrowseTable">
  <h4>Open / Unfilled</h4>

  <?php renderRequestDataTable('open') ?>
</div>
```

As I removed more logic to isolate the problem, it became clear that data passage to the child template is causing an issue:

```
// requestDataTable.php
<table class="ui striped table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Request</th>
    <th>Customer</th>
    <th>Products</th>
    <th>Notes</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <?php
  global $tradeInRequestData;
  var_dump($tradeInRequestData); // null
  foreach ($tradeInRequestData['data'] as $r):
    if ($r['status'] === 'open'):
      $productString = implode(', ', $r['products']);
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span>ID:</span>
          <span contenteditable>
                <?php echo "{$r['id']}"; ?>
              </span>
          // continues
```

This table worked when it was part of the parent template file's HTML. Only when it was moved into its own file did it break. The table headers continue to display but the record / row data does not, since the data object is null.

Does anyone see the mistake in my data passage?

**Update 1**

By marking `$tradeInRequestData` as a global where it was initially declared, the bug went away. However this variable becomes null again when I unmark it as global and then try to pass it as an argument:

```
function renderRequestDataTable(array $data, string $requestStatus) {
  require_once(__DIR__ . "/../components/requestDataTable.php");
}

// HTML portion of the template, in the same file
  <?php renderRequestDataTable($tradeInRequestData, 'open') ?>
```

Comment: Perhaps your high level template file is not in the global scope?

Comment: I thought anything in the outer scope of the file is automatically globally scoped? If not any idea from the code above how to scope the data object correctly?

Comment: I cannot determine the scope of that outer file.  That is why I ask.  Are you using namespaces?

Comment: No, there are no namespaces explicitly declared. I should note these files are being used inside a wordpress plugin although I don't think that is affecting the issue

Comment: That could well be the cause of your issue, if this code isn't in the global scope.  Try declaring your variable global before you assign the value (`global 
$tradeInRequestData;`).

Comment: setting $tradeInRequestData to global on the outer scope has fixed the problem, thank you. If you would like to post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Try and avoid globals if you can.  You could pass the data as an argument to your function.

Comment: @Progrock I tried parameterizing the data as an input and then adding the file scoped variable but it broke the code again. It shows null once again. I'm posting the changes above as Update 1, what did I do wrong?

Comment: It probably becomes null, as your parameter name in your function declaration is $data, not $tradeInRequestData.

Comment: @Progrock but during the function call I pass in `$tradeRequestData` to that argument. And I think that is where it matters to pass in the variable that the function should use. Is that wrong?

Comment: Okay, I see the issue. The template is essentially scoped inside the function so the local variable needs to used used throughout the child template as well